# Jquery UI Dialog + Jquery Repeats its Functions when Cancelled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

please help me on this
Q1: When i clicked the Cancel Button, all the functions seems to repeat calling itself, and I only encounter this in IE

my HTML

```
<button class="btnCaller">diag caller 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btnCaller">diag caller 2</button >

<table id="diagMenu" style="display:none">
    <tr><td>
        <input id="anyField"></input>
        <button id="cmdInsertNewProject">Ok</button >
        <button id="cmdCancelNewProject">Cancel</button >
        </td></tr>  

</table>
```

my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btnCaller').click(function() {
        fnAddNewProject()
        AddNewProject_ShowUI()
    })
});

function fnAddNewProject() {
    $('#diagMenu').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 650,
        maxHeight: 1000,
        maxWidth: 600,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Insert New Project",
        position: "center"
    })

    $('#btnRun').click(function() {
       alert("do other stuff")
    })
    $('#cmdInsertNewProject').live('click', function() {
        InsertNewProject();
    })

    $('#cmdCancelNewProject').live('click', function() {
        $('#diagMenu').dialog('close');
    })
}  

function InsertNewProject() {
    if ($('#anyField').val() == '') {
        alert("Fill up field to continue") //dont close the dialog
        return false
    } else {
        //reset and exit
        $('#anyField').val('')
        $('#diagMenu').dialog('close');
    }
}

function AddNewProject_ShowUI() {
    $('#diagMenu').dialog('open');
}
```

i have this on jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/aeris/Qn9HE/

Comment: the table diagMenu in my web app will be re-printed so the cmdInsertNewProject and cmdCancelNewProject are "Live"

Comment: As an aside, don't use 'live' - use 'on' instead. http://bitovi.com/blog/2011/04/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live.html

Comment: thanks everyone, my initial idea was that evertime i call fnAddNewProject it would "reset" all events.. but instead its stacking the events...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with how you're registering the event handlers. The click event handlers should be added only once, so this can be done in `ready()` method.

Also what ever you are doing in `fnAddNewProject()` should be done only once, not on every `click` so you can move the function call to `ready()`

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn9HE/19/).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.live('click',
```

to

```
.click(
```

and that should fix your problems, I think.

EDIT:

according to http://api.jquery.com/live/, it appears that the .live() command is deprecated. Try using .on() instead.

Comment: thanks coder543, because the diagMenu needs to be re-printed in its Div, so i need its button to be Live

Comment: You're calling the .live() command on every single dialog creation, which is causing events to stack up. Either it needs to be called in $(document).ready() or it needs to be .click(). which will it be?

Answer (score 0):

So, as it has already been pointed out, the way you are registering your handler with the dialog is causing it to be reregistered every time the event happens. As a result, you get the popup repeatedly (because of the new registration every single time).

With that said, you can make use of jQueryUI's dialog's buttons property to attach your buttons (and the corresponding functions) to your dialog and not have to worry about all this event registration. I didn't complete it, but I [updated your example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn9HE/20/) (you'll note - it's a lot more simple). Please note the "buttons" property that is part of the dialog.

```
$('#diagMenu').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 650,
    maxHeight: 1000,
    maxWidth: 600,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: "Insert New Project",
    position: "center",
    buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
            InsertNewProject();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```